# Why DjangoObjectPermissions is not working for admin user?

Tags: django, object, django-rest-framework, permissions

**Problem:** I have assigned DjangoObjectPermissions which is working perfectly working for normal users but Its not workign for admin users.

---

**models.py**

```
class Transformer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    alternate_mode = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    alive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

**serializers.py**

```
class TransformerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transformer
        fields = "__all__"
```

---

**views.py**

```
class TransformerList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Transformer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransformerSerializer
    permission_classes = [DjangoObjectPermissions, ]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save()
        assign_perm("delete_transformer", self.request.user, instance)

class TransformerDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Transformer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransformerSerializer
    permission_classes = [DjangoObjectPermissions, ]
```

---

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'snippets',
    'class_based_api_views',
    'guardian'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)
```

**Testing**

created admin user -> username=admin

created normal user -> username=user3


created one transformer post using `user3` user.


**Object detail view**
[Image of Object detail view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlfYA.png)
**Object's permission**
[Image of object's permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP4ZK.png)
**user3 can delete his own post as expected**
[Image for user3 can delete his own post as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otTPa.png)
**Admin can do everything on object: not expected**
[Admin can do everything on object: not expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq24A.png)

**Question:** Why Admin user can edit/delete object which he dont have permission.

Comment: By admin user do you mean a superuser - `is_superuser = True`?

Comment: In this sense, a superuser is an admin user. I tested it out on is staff and non-superuser users, and it functions well for them. Is it because of is_superuser that it only fails for superusers?

Comment: superuser has access to all resources regardless of defined permissions.

Comment: oh god, thank you so much I was so much confused about that. Can you answer my question, so that i can tick mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Superuser has access to all resources regardless of defined permissions.**